# NetSuite saved search to pull backorder quantity based on location

Tags: netsuite, inventory, saved-searches

I am trying to build an item saved search to pull the quantity backorder based on location. There are 8 locations in NetSuite. I would like to get backorder quantity from 3 locations. In the criteria I have added the "Inventory Location" is any of "Loc1, Loc2, Loc3".

In the results section, when I add the field "Back Ordered" and preview the results it's showing me the sum of backordered quantity of all locations. I would like to get the backordered quantity of three locations. Is there a way to pull the Back Ordered quantity based on location?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In results tabs  add location field and in the summarytype "Group" should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Yes

Instead of using the column "Back Ordered" in your search use the column "Location Back Ordered" and include "Inventory Location" as one of your columns.

When multi-location is turned on then for each of the aggregate fields there is a "Location X" field that gives the quantity value for a location.